# "The requested resource was not found" When submitting a form in liferay portlet

Tags: liferay

I'm developing a liferay portlet. This is not my first time doing that, but a get a simple error that I can't understand why I'm getting this error. When I click submit button I get this error

> The requested resource was not found. "http://localhost:8081/addProduct"

It's more than hours I'm trying to solve it and I know that I have made a silly mistake. Can any body help me solve this problem? Any help is appreciated in advance. Here is my jsp code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui" %>
<%@ page import="javax.portlet.PortletURL" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

This is the <b>ServiceBuilderTest</b> portlet.
<portlet:actionURL var="addProduct" name="addProductAction"/>

<aui:form method="post" action="addProduct">
    <aui:fieldset>
        <aui:input name="productName" label="Product Name"></aui:input>
        <aui:input name="userID" label="User ID"></aui:input>
        <aui:input name="companyID" label="company ID"></aui:input>
        <aui:input name="groupID" label="Group ID"></aui:input>     
        <aui:input name="serialNumber" label="Serial Number"></aui:input>   
        <aui:button type="submit" value="Submit"></aui:button>  
    </aui:fieldset>
</aui:form>
```

And this is my portlet class code:

```
public class ServiceBuilderPortlet extends MVCPortlet{
    public void addProductAction(ActionRequest actionReauest, ActionResponse         actionResponse) throws SystemException, PortalException
    {               
        String productName = actionReauest.getParameter("productName");
        String userID = actionReauest.getParameter("userID");
        String companyID = actionReauest.getParameter("companyID");
        String groupID = actionReauest.getParameter("groupID");
        String serialNumber = actionReauest.getParameter("serialNumber");
        PRProduct product =     PRProductLocalServiceUtil.addProduct(Long.parseLong(companyID), Long.parseLong(groupID),     productName, 
                serialNumber, Long.parseLong(userID));                  
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the exception as well as your mvcPortlet code

Comment: `public void addProductAction(ActionRequest actionReauest, ActionResponse         actionResponse) throws SystemException, PortalException
    { }` shouldnt the name of the method be `addProduct`?

Comment: No. <portlet:actionURL var="addProduct" name="addProductAction"/> The name property is the method name.

Comment: In [every](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Alloy+UI+Forms+%28aui%29#section-Alloy+UI+Forms+(aui)-Form) name attribute it says it always is something like name of the field. Are you really sure the name attribute here describes the name of the action? Especially because your error seems to look for the `addProduct` method aswell!

Comment: I even changed my method name. it didn't help. The problem solved. The action property of form should be in this format : action="<%=addProduct %>". Thanks Matthias G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make it

```
<portlet:actionURL var="addProduct" name="addProductAction"/>
<aui:form method="post" action="<%=addProduct%>">
   ...
```

actually, I'd see it as best practice to not name the action "addProductAction", but just "addProduct", so the changes would be as such (including one line of java, the rest looks good (visually, not tried/tested):

```
<portlet:actionURL var="addProduct" name="addProduct"/>
<aui:form method="post" action="<%=addProduct%>">
  ....
```

and

```
public class ServiceBuilderPortlet extends MVCPortlet{
   public void addProduct(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws SystemException, PortalException { 
       // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: You are right Olaf. Thanks for your answer. By the way do you have any experience working with Service Builder? I have problems working with it.

Comment: well, go ahead and ask the next question and we'll see (but I don't know if I can answer during the next day - it's quite busy here this week)

Comment: OK. I will post my question. Thanks in advance.